# Error while executing a Stored Procedure (Expecting: error)

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, triggers

I am trying to execute an already-defined stored procedure inside a trigger. When I tried to execute the below mentioned piece of code I am getting this error :

```
ERROR line 22, col 9, ending_line 22, ending_col 22, Found 'pat_lines_proc',
Expecting: ;   -or-   :=   -or-   .  -or-   (   -or-   @   -or-   ROW
```

This is how I am calling the procedure inside the trigger and getting the above mentioned error:

```
create or replace trigger pat_lines_trig 
after insert on pat_headers_all 
for each row
begin
   call pat_lines_proc (&p_lineno,&p_diseasename,&p_PAT_HEADERS_ID);
end;
/
```

This is how I have defined that procedure and this piece of code worked fine:

```
Create or Replace procedure pat_lines_proc(
p_lineno in pat_lines.LINE_NO%type, 
p_diseasename in pat_lines.DISEASE_NAME%type,
p_pat_headers_id in pat_lines.PAT_HEADERS_ID%type
)
is
begin 
insert into pat_lines 
values(
pat_lines_seq.nextval,
p_lineno,
p_diseasename,
p_pat_headers_id
);
end pat_lines_proc;
```

What seems to be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed column names so substitute correct column names when passing values to procedure, try creating your trigger as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pat_lines_trig
   AFTER INSERT
   ON pat_headers_all
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   pat_lines_proc (:new.p_lineno, :new.p_diseasename, :new.p_PAT_HEADERS_ID);
END;
/
```